# Arduino keeps blinking when LED is in high

Tags: arduino-uno

I have implemented a very simple program that turns a LED off when a switch is pressed.

My code works, but, when the LED is in high state, the LED blinks fast then turns off.

When I try to use the switch, the LED lights up without me even touching the switch. It seems like there is an invisible current that flows.

Observing carefully, I found out that the body of my laptop is probably causing this issue. My laptop has a metal body.

Since my Arduino is powered via USB from my Laptop, on "HIGH" state and I touch the body of my laptop, the LED turns off but when I let go of my laptop, the LED turns back on but blinks very fast.

Pushing the switch button, turns off the LED but when I release the button, the LED lights up but blinks very fast again.

I tried using a power adapter set to 12V but it just lights up the LED on the arduino board but not the LED on the breadboard.

I tried plugging the USB to a desktop, it lights up the LEDs on the arduino board but not the LED on the breadboard as well.

The schema is like below. 
[image]

My code works. It's just the rapid blinking stuff. Is it the static electricity or noise or something that is causing this issue?

```
const int ledPin = 13;
const int buttonPin = 7;

int buttonState = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED ON +++++++++++");
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("LED OFF ------------");
  }
}
```

Comment: Post a schematic of your connection.

Comment: Please see the update above.

Comment: *My code works, but, ...* - please post that code.

Comment: I can actually see in my serial command that the "LED ON +++++++" then immediately goes to  "LED OFF ----------". This goes on and on when I am not touching the switch.

Comment: Try making buttonPin `INPUT_PULLUP`. And get rid of that resistor between the button and earth (what is that for?).

Comment: @NickGammon, it is a button which signals HIGH if pressed and needs pull-down to signal LOW. I know it is stupid, but the tutorials teach this https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Comment: @stackquestions, always use this button connection https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial

Comment: I am just following a tutorial and trying to figure things out. Thank you @Nick. Your suggestion worked!

Comment: `The schema is like below.`  Is it *like* that, or is it *actually* that?

Comment: This weird behavior sound a lot like a floating input. Double check the connections on the pull-down resistor you are using. Try wiggling the wires in the breadboard. Sometimes you get a bad connection in a breadboards. Also note that some breadboards don't have the blue and red lines connected all the way, but have a split in the middle (though that's not applicable if your wiring is exactly the way is shown in the picture).

Comment: The input impedance of a digital pin is extremely high. When something changes if you touch something or move your hand, that is an indication of a floating input pin. I prefer that all inputs and outputs have a GND connection, therefor I prefer that one side of the button is connected to GND, and the other one with INPUT_PULLUP or an extra pullup resistor.

Comment: @Juraj *I know it is stupid, but the tutorials teach this arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button* - that page shows a Fritzing picture which does **not** match the schematic further down the page. On the schematic the resistor is in a different place.

Comment: remove the ground wire to the LED.  use the busbar ground for the LED (same as the switch) .... the arduino already has an LED on pin 13, use that